# Menu with submenu. Pc,tablets and cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's a code of menu with a submenu and Don't work the submenu.  The menu code, work for pc and tablets but submenu don't work.  Also, I'd like the submenu work like acordion in tablet.

```js
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main (){
    $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
        // $('nav').toggle(); Forma Sencilla de aparecer y desaparecer

        if (contador == 1){
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '0'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        };

    });
};
```

```css
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FalconMasters';
    src:url('../fonts/FalconMasters.eot?-ibh2ms');
    src:url('../fonts/FalconMasters.eot?#iefix-ibh2ms') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/FalconMasters.woff?-ibh2ms') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/FalconMasters.ttf?-ibh2ms') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/FalconMasters.svg?-ibh2ms#FalconMasters') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'FalconMasters';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-mail:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-house:before {
    content: "\e622";
}
.icon-rocket:before {
    content: "\e650";
}
.icon-suitcase:before {
    content: "\e652";
}
.icon-earth:before {
    content: "\e654";
}
.icon-cross:before {
    content: "\e678";
}
.icon-list2:before {
    content: "\e696";
}



* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
 background:#FFFFFA;
}

header {
 width:100%;
}

header nav {
 width:100%;
 max-width:1000px;
 background:#024959;
}

.menu_bar {
 display:none;
}

nav ul {
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
}

nav ul li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 line-height:20px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav ul li span {
 margin-right:10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 background:#037E8C;
}

section {
 padding:20px;
}

/*Sub-menu*/
nav .submenu1{
  position:relative;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#submenu a:hover .submenu1{
    display: block;
    background-color:#D90B0F;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px ) {
 header nav {
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  left:-100%;
  margin:0;
  position: fixed;
 }

 header nav ul li {
  display:block;
  float:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255, .3);
 }

 .menu_bar {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:#ccc;
 }

 .menu_bar .bt-menu {
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  background:#024959;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }

 .menu_bar span {
  float:right;
  font-size:40px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/7d96e2500b/UntitledProject7/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/menuH.css">

<title>index</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <div class="menu_bar">
   <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-list2"></span>Menu</a>
  </div>

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-house"></span>Inicio</a></li>
    <li id="submenu"><a href="#"><span class="icon-suitcase"></span>Trabajos</a>
     <ul class="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #5</a></li>
        </ul>
     
     </li>
        
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-rocket"></span>Proyectos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-earth"></span>Servicios</a></li> 
    <li id="submenu"><a href="#"><span class="icon-mail"></span>Contactos</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
#submenu a:hover .submenu1{
    display: block;
    background-color:#D90B0F;
}
```

why?

--------------- css 3 -------------

```
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FalconMasters';
    src:url('../fonts/FalconMasters.eot?-ibh2ms');
    src:url('../fonts/FalconMasters.eot?#iefix-ibh2ms') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/FalconMasters.woff?-ibh2ms') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/FalconMasters.ttf?-ibh2ms') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/FalconMasters.svg?-ibh2ms#FalconMasters') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'FalconMasters';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-mail:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-house:before {
    content: "\e622";
}
.icon-rocket:before {
    content: "\e650";
}
.icon-suitcase:before {
    content: "\e652";
}
.icon-earth:before {
    content: "\e654";
}
.icon-cross:before {
    content: "\e678";
}
.icon-list2:before {
    content: "\e696";
}



* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
 background:#FFFFFA;
}

header {
 width:100%;
}

header nav {
 width:100%;
 max-width:1000px;
 background:#024959;
}

.menu_bar {
 display:none;
}

nav ul {
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
}

nav ul li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 line-height:20px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav ul li span {
 margin-right:10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 background:#037E8C;
}

section {
 padding:20px;
}

/*Sub-menu*/
nav .submenu1{
  position:relative;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#submenu a:hover .submenu1{
    display: block;
    background-color:#D90B0F;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px ) {
 header nav {
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  left:-100%;
  margin:0;
  position: fixed;
 }

 header nav ul li {
  display:block;
  float:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255, .3);
 }

 .menu_bar {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  background:#ccc;
 }

 .menu_bar .bt-menu {
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  background:#024959;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }

 .menu_bar span {
  float:right;
  font-size:40px;
 }
}
```

-------------------- html5 ------------------

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/7d96e2500b/UntitledProject7/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/menuH.css">

<title>index</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <div class="menu_bar">
   <a href="#" class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-list2"></span>Menu</a>
  </div>

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-house"></span>Inicio</a></li>
    <li id="submenu"><a href="#"><span class="icon-suitcase"></span>Trabajos</a></li>
        <ul class="submenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Item #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item #5</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-rocket"></span>Proyectos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-earth"></span>Servicios</a></li>
    <li id="submenu"><a href="#"><span class="icon-mail"></span>Contactos</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1;

function main (){
    $('.menu_bar').click(function(){
        // $('nav').toggle(); Forma Sencilla de aparecer y desaparecer

        if (contador == 1){
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '0'
            });
            contador = 0;
        } else {
            contador = 1;
            $('nav').animate({
                left: '-100%'
            });
        };

    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new class to use "toggleClass" with your menu. Like this:

```
.show_menu_bar {
  left:0;
}
```

And add a transition to nav for the animation:

```
header nav {
 width:100%;
 max-width:1000px;
 background:#024959;
 transition: all ease .4s;
 position: relative;
}
```

I recommend you use the method "on" on jQuery. You can read how it works [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu_bar', function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('show_menu_bar');
});
```

To animate the submenu adds a class to the main menu button and use "on()" again

```
$(document).on('click', '.display_submenu', function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

CSS for submenu:

```
nav .display_submenu + * {
  position: absolute !important;
  top:100%;
  background: #024959;
}
@media screen and (max-width:800px ) {
  nav .display_submenu + * {
    position: relative !important;
    top:auto;
    background: inherit;
  }
}
```

You can see this example working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecruz/a3dw16ks/8/). Greetings from Mexico